# how can i add key value pair in array inside another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//  I have the following response :

```
    [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",

"company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },


 {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",

"company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },

 ]
```

//and I want to add this key-value pair in 2 places ("completed": false) to make it look like the following response:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
     **"completed": false**

"company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
       **"completed": false**
    }
  },


 {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
     **"completed": false**
     "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
     **"completed": false**
    }
  },  
  
]
```

.......................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` can solve your problem.

```
const result = input.map(x => {
    x.completed = false;
    x.company = x.company.map(c => ({ ...c, completed: false }))
    return x;
})
```

You can check the completed demo:

```js
const input = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "company": [{
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }, {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }]
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "company": [{
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }, {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }]
  },
];

const result = input.map(x => {
  x.completed = false;
  x.company = x.company.map(c => ({ ...c, completed: false }))
  return x;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: company key is an array with multiple elements I want to assign the false value with each element

Comment: @vivekchaudhary I've updated the result to let `company` to be array. You can try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) if you want to keep you original data and treat the array as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

```js
const users = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 3,
    title: "fugiat veniam minus",
    company: {
      name: "Deckow-Crist",
      catchPhrase: "Proactive didactic contingency",
      bs: "synergize scalable supply-chains",
    },
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    id: 4,
    title: "fugiat veniam minus",
    company: {
      name: "Deckow-Crist",
      catchPhrase: "Proactive didactic contingency",
      bs: "synergize scalable supply-chains",
    },
  },
];

const revisedUsers = users.map(user => ({
    ...user,
    completed: false,
    company: {
        ...user.company,
        completed: false
    }
}))

console.log(`
-----------------
Result
-----------------`)
console.log(revisedUsers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Array manipulation

You can map your array into a new one using `Array.prototype.map` which loops over each item of an array and you can return any type of data from callback function to be added into new array.

```js
const mappedArray = yourArray.map(user => {
    user.completed = false;
    user.company.completed = false;
    return user;
});
```

### Using spread operator

```js
const mappedArray = yourArray.map(user => {
    return {
        ...user,
        completed: false,
        company: {
            ...user.company,
            completed: false,
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways to achieve adding properties to an array of objects. I will write a simple array map function to demonstrate, considering you have a response in the variable of data

```
data = data.map((obj) => ({ ...obj, company: { ...obj.company, completed: false }, completed: false }));
```

Comment: He also needs `completed` inside company property.

Comment: right thats the challenging part for me I need the key inside the company as well

Answer (score 0):

Using the `...` operator with `Array.map`:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
        "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
    },

    {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 4,
        "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
        "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
    }
];

console.log(arr.map(arrObj => ({...arrObj, company: {...arrObj["company"], completed: false}, completed: false})));
```